# d3 Circle Packing - Printing labels with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm brand new to `d3` (and `JavaScript` in general), and I'm trying to figure out how to alter [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530) so that each circle has its corresponding size field printed below the name. I tried just altering the JSON so the name fields were something like `"MergeEdge\n743"`, but this did not work (it seems to just ignore the newline and print all on one line). Any tips?

Comment: The newline character is ignored in HTML, and you won't be able to use `<br>` inside the `<text>` SVG element. You will need to modify the code to append a new `<text>` element with that number.

Comment: Good question, I'm having a similar issue with the flare graph here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49757785/d3-render-flare-graph-titles-avoiding-text-overlap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tip, usually with d3 you prefer to have separate code for different objectives. It makes it easier to maintain and overall make it more understandable when you read your file. 
In your case, we need to add a new text field, with coordinates which place the text below the current one. So we need to add :

```
node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d.r).toString(); });
```

So the entire javaScript code will be :

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(2,2)"),
    format = d3.format(",d");

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4]);

d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = d3.hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; });

  node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.3em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name.substring(0, d.r / 3); });

  node.filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }).append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d.r).toString(); });
});
```